# What is the most efficient way to find the greatest result of millions of calculations?

Tags: memory, optimization, language-agnostic, cpu-usage

Basically, I'm doing millions of very simple calculations and trying to store the highest result to be printed at the end. I'm using a C# console application, but this is simple enough as to be very language agnostic (Would this perform substantially better in another language?)

What I have:

```
double output = 0;
//do the calculations
//after each:
if(calculationResult > output) output = calculationResult;
//done with calculations
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

This works, but it takes a very long time to complete. I thought about storing the answers in a list and sorting it after calculations, but it crashed as OutOfMemory around 9GB.

Comparing live and only storing one takes too long, but storing all and comparing later takes too much memory. Is there any way to optimize this?

EDIT: My solution was to first cut the number of calculations in half by moving on after reaching the vertex of the parabola formed by the answers. I then realized the best solution would be to refactor everything to be recursive, starting at low precision and wide scope and then narrowing down while increasing precision. Moving to C++ with Intel's IPP only provided about an 8% decrease in completion time, whereas reduction of operations was about 99%. I'm working on recursion now and will report back.

Comment: Besides of optimizing the calculation, you can visualize the progress (with a progress bar, with local maximum) and stopping when/if the absolute maximum is reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Matthew says, you need to make the process more efficient. In addition to finding a better algorithm, here are some suggestions:

1. Are the calculations dependent upon one another? Can you multi-thread and spread them across multiple cores?
2. Can you vectorized them, meaning use SSE, AVX, AVX2, etc?
3. Use a good optimizing compiler, such as Intel's. It's one of the best optimizing compilers around. It will parallelize for you automagically in many cases.
4. Restructure your code to exploit the cache hierarchy and minimize misses.
5. If you can do both 1 and 2, you can get a remarkable speed up. For example, if you have a quad core machine with hyperthreading, and AVX256, you have 8 virtual cores running in parallel, each executing AVX256 (4 double precision values), allowing you to execute 32 calculations in parallel. You can imagine the speed up under ideal conditions if you are using a server class machine with 2 sockets and 32 cores each running AVX512.
6. Find an algorithm that allows you to exploit the above.
7. Use Fortran. I'm not kidding. For numerical calculations, it can't be beat. And it avoids a lot of optimization issues given how it stores data.

Take a look at [Intel's site](http://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Asoftware.intel.com%20optimization&qs=HS&pq=site%3A&sc=8-5&sp=1&cvid=AF202F3F1C204C879256312E9EFD7224&FORM=QBLH). They want you to be able to exploit as much parallelism as possible for various reasons that I won't go into here.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly what is slow is the calculation step, not the `if(calculationResult > output) output = calculationResult;` section.

I have no idea what your particular problem is, but often the most efficient way to find the greatest of millions of calculations is to think through your problem carefully and use a more efficient algorithm and/or math *so you don't have to make millions of calculations*.

Comment: Thanks. My case involves parabolas, so I can skip to the next set after passing the vertex, essentially halving the total.